# Assigning the entirety of a 2D packed array to a 1D packed array with the same number of elements

Tags: arrays, system-verilog, hdl, register-transfer-level

I have the following signals:

```
logic [X-1:0][Y-1:0] twoDim;
logic [(X*Y)-1:0]    oneDim;
```

I want to assign the entirety of `twoDim` to `oneDim` i.e. if I wrote something like this:

```
assign oneDim = twoDim;
```

And `parameter X = 5` then I would expect the behaviour to be the same as the following:

```
assign oneDim = { twoDim[4], twoDim[3], twoDim[2], twoDim[1], twoDim[0] };
```

How would this be accomplished succintly in Synthesizable SystemVerilog for all possible values of X, Y (which are `int unsigned`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For packed aggregate types, you do not need to go through all this trouble. The following will be sufficient. System verilog allows assigning arrays of compatible types (7.6).

```
   assign oneDim = twoDim;
```

Comment: Incredible, I never considered the fact that, even if the arrays are nominally 2 Dimensional or X Dimensional, if they are packed then they are exactly equivalent to 1 Dimensional array in representation.

Answer (score 2):

If you try such assignment you will get an error because the synthetizer does not know about the structure of your 2D array and how it can flatten it. In your case you want to store the rows one after the other, which is called row-major arrangement.

You can produce synthetizable code with a generate for loop:

```
  localparam X = 10; // N rows
  localparam Y = 20; // N cols
  
  // Note I swapped X and Y dimensions 
  logic [Y-1:0][X-1:0] twoDim;
  logic [(X*Y)-1:0]    oneDim;
  
  genvar i;
  generate 
    for (i = 0; i < X; i = i + 1) begin
      assign oneDim[i*Y +: Y] = twoDim[i];
    end
  endgenerate;
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the for generate construct here? It is very verbose.

Comment: I don't find it very verbose, however you can use an `always` block with blocking assignments to achieve the same result. It is however a bit more prone to errors, and not really less verbose.